# int x = x; Что произойдёт?

Tags: c++

Что произойдёт в результате такой инструкции:

```
int x = x;
```

?

Comment: А какого **наблюдаемого поведения** вы от этой инструкции ожидаете? :)

Comment: @D-side наблюдаемого не ожидаю. Хочу узнать, что в принципе будет выполнено

Comment: @valuev, что мешает самостоятельно попробовать разные варианты и посмотреть что будет?

Comment: @insolor не разбираюсь в ассемблере на должном уровне

Comment: @valuev, при чем здесь ассемблер, это C++.

Comment: @insolor тогда какие "разные варианты" вы предлагаете рассмотреть?

Comment: @valuev, см. ответ от pavel, там три варианта. Их можно было рассмотреть самостоятельно, и знание ассемблера тут не требуется.

Comment: Предполагаю, топикстартера интересует, выкинет ли компилятор ненужное присваивание (при условии, что это одна и та же переменная).

Answer (score 11):

Если в данной области видимости *уже определена* переменная `x`, это не откомпилируется:

```
int x = 0;
int x = x; // <-- ошибка, повторная декларация переменной
```

http://ideone.com/3VGhe0

Если в данной области видимости нет переменной `x` (например, она вовсе не определена, или определена во внешней области), то это откомпилируется, но программа [будет иметь *неопределённое поведение*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14991772/276994). Это означает, что вам даже не гарантировано, что в переменной будет какой-то мусор. Программа имеет право делать всё, что угодно: с точки зрения компилятора она бессмысленна. Никогда так не делайте: компилятор C++ считает вас достаточно взрослым и ответственным, и не проверяет, следуете ли вы правилам.

---

Да, я не знаю, почему в таком случае компилятор не выдаёт ошибку. Другие языки доверяют программисту меньше и контролируют.

Comment: а формально в чём тут ошибка? объявление произошло до знака равенства, после чего делается бессмысленное присваивание. Или я не так понимаю что именно происходит?

Comment: @pavel: Вы имеете в виду первый или второй случай? В первом — переопределение переменной, которое запрещено правилами. Во втором использование неинициализированного значения, которое есть UB по стандерту.

Comment: @pavel: В C++ строке `int x = initializer;` переменная `x` существует и доступна после знака `=`, а не после `;`. Поэтому `int x = x;` делает ссылку на себя.

Comment: Компиляторы выдают предупреждения, во всяком случае на подобном коде внутри функций. Я уж было собрал коллекцию предупреждений из GCC, clang и MSVC, но в конечном счёте решил, что на ответ это не тянет. Я б посоветовал включать все предупреждения и обработку их как ошибок. М-м-м-м-максимум строгости.

Comment: @D-side: gcc вроде не выдал: http://ideone.com/cvtZso

Comment: @VladD не уверен, что ideone вообще их показывает, если скомпилялось. Я проверял локально с `-Wall`.

Comment: @D-side: А вот это может быть, да.

Comment: @VladD, на codepad'е действует warnings as errors... Но что-то он сейчас дохлый...

Comment: http://codepad.org/riPwHLDH - вот предупреждение)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну да, но это предупреждение. Оно не нормативно. Компилятор, видя UB, имеет право сделать что угодно (даже упасть, кстати).

Answer (score 2):

Смотря в каком месте находится, эта строка.

Есть три вида памяти, динамическая, статическая и куча.

1] Динамическая память:
выделяется обычно new, malloc, alloc..итд
выделяется память и там лежит мусор (остатки предыдущей работы)
но в некоторые маллоки заполняют память 0, а так же new конструктор может заполнять память

2] статическая память (глоб перемен, static):
Память выделяется компилятором и заполняется нулевым значением.
Ее можно увидеть в бинарнике и изменить.

3] стек (int x внутри функции):
память выделяется, но в ней мусор.

Comment: Какой-то недоответ. Стоило бы сказать, что происходит в каждом из тих случаев. Ну и ещё, объявить переменную в динамической памяти не выйдет.

Comment: Какой то недовопрос. =) Уточни где находится данная строка. Внутри функции или в глобальной переменной.

Answer (score 2):

Произойдет **на практике** ровно то же самое, что и при простом объявлении

```
int x;
```

Однако **в теории** это - undefined behaviour, так что все, что угодно...

Этот вопрос упоминался у Саттера в "*Сложных задачах*", а именно в задаче 9.1, постскриптум 1.

Есть еще один подобный код, но с оператором`new`:

```
T t;
new(&t) T(t);
```

Comment: Не факт. Присваивание неинициализированной переменной - это UB, а вот объявление без инициализации - нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy Вы поспешили с комментарием, я уже исправил ответ, найдя у Саттера это место.

Comment: Не могу найти. Можно точно назвать книгу и номер страницы?

Comment: @Qwertiy Герб Саттер. *Решение сложных задач на C++. Серия C++ In-Depth.* - М.: Издательский дом "Вильямс", 2002. Стр. 339.

Comment: Я только 2008 год нашёл. Там 9.1 на стр. 338 про `if (this != &other )`. Продолжать искать 2002?

Comment: А на следующей странице внизу этот пример в примечании.

Comment: А, в сноске. Нашёл. Но там говорится `T t = t; // Некорректно, но придает смысл проверке`